# create or update python dictionary entry

Tags: python, dictionary

Perhaps I've been spoiled by Brand X programming languages, but is there a better pythonic idiom for the following?

```
thing_dict = {}

def find_or_create_thing(key):
    if (thing_dict.has_key(key)):
        thing = thing_dict[key]
    else:
        thing = create_new_thing(key)
        thing_dict[key] = thing
    return thing
```

It seems like something like this could be done in one or two lines.  I considered using a [Conditional Expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), but Python's odd syntax simply didn't lend itself to legibility.

I also considered a `try: ... except KeyError:`, but that was just about as much text and probably considerably more execution overhead.

*P.S. I know that asking programming style questions on S.O. is problematic, but I'll take my chances...*

Answer (score 1):

Using `in` is more Pythonic

```
thing_dict = {}

def find_or_create_thing(key):
    if not key in thing_dict:
        thing_dict[key] = create_new_thing(key)
    return thing_dict[key]
```

If you absolutely need the function on two lines:

```
thing_dict = {}

def find_or_create_thing(key):
    if not key in thing_dict: thing_dict[key] = create_new_thing(key)
    return thing_dict[key]
```

Comment: The second one is inefficient and may have unwanted side-effects as `create_new_thing` is called for each `get()`.

Comment: The problem with the second approach is that `create_new_thing(key)` is always called

Comment: Using `in` *is* more Pythonic.  My only nit with the above solution is that it does an extra dict lookup in the case where it creates a new thing.  (The O.P. adds extra lines to avoid that.)

Comment: I see. But how would you know wether or not to create an entry without looking it up? Im thinking hard here :D

Comment: > how would you know whether or not to create an entry? \n Well, @MichaelButscher shows one way to make that decision "at the source".  Or you could replicate the O.P. and simply use `in`.

Answer (score 1):

Not much shorter but maybe "prettier" (depending on the use case):

```
class ThingDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = create_new_thing(key)
        return self[key]

thing_dict = ThingDict()

def find_or_create_thing(key):
    return thing_dict[key]
```